# Rssi Value Difference Between Different Platforms

Tags: android, rssi

Currently i am doing in door localization using Rssi.I get different rssi values my computer using inSSIDer program and my android phone my own program which use WifiManager.

I wonder why there is such difference between laptop rssi value and android phone rssi value?

Answer (score 0):

Because RSSI isn't defined in any absolute fashion, and different Wi-Fi adapters and different Wi-Fi drivers and different Wi-Fi frameworks can report the values differently.  As the IEEE 802.11 standard says, RSSI values should only be used "in a relative manner", which means you should only use it to compare measurements done with the same adapter - don't use it to compare measurements done with different adapters.